# Place ipywidgets into HTML into Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, html, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

With the following minimal example, I can create buttons which interact with the Jupyter notebook and an HTML table, which is displayed in the notebook.

```
import ipywidgets
from IPython.display import display

from IPython.core.display import HTML

def func(btn):
    print('Hi!')

btn1 = ipywidgets.Button(description="Click me!")
btn1.on_click(func)
btn2 = ipywidgets.Button(description="Click me!")
btn2.on_click(func)
display(btn1)
display(btn2)

display(HTML(
        '<table>' +
        '<tr><td>Something here</td><td>Button 1 here</td></tr>' +
        '<tr><td>Something here</td><td>Button 2 here</td></tr>' +
        '</table>'
    ))
```

The produced result is:
[image: screenshot of table and buttons]

I now would like to place the buttons in the html table. I tried investigating the method `Widget._ipython_display_()` but this does not allow me to use the button inside my own html table.

(Please see the small table as an example. I want to place the buttons in a large table and use the buttons to delete rows from a database.)

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37013489/how-to-alight-and-place-ipywidgets), the wanted to know, how to place widgets relative to each other. Here, I want to place the widgets inside other HTML code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be an easy way to achieve this. You will either have to build a custom ipywidget to display a table, or manually write the code for an HTML button of which you'll have full control.

The best I could find was a way to emulate a table using an array of VBoxes inside an HBox:

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display

def func(btn):
    print('Hi!')

btn1 = widgets.Button(description="Click me!")
btn1.on_click(func)
btn2 = widgets.Button(description="Click me!")
btn2.on_click(func)

# This is where you fill your table
cols = [
    # Each tuple contains a column header and a list of items/widgets
    ('Col1', ['hello', 'goodbye']),
    ('Col2', ['world', 'universe']),
    ('Buttons', [btn1, btn2]),
]

vboxes = []
for header, data in cols:
    vboxes.append(widgets.VBox([widgets.HTML('<b>%s</b>' % header)] + [
        d if isinstance(d, widgets.Widget) else widgets.HTML(str(d)) for d in data],
    layout=widgets.Layout(border='1px solid')))

hbox = widgets.HBox(vboxes)

display(hbox)
```

Result:

[image]