# Changing description color in ipywidgets Text widget not working

Tags: jupyter-notebook, widget, ipywidgets, datalore

I'm trying to change the description color of an ipywidgets Text widget in Datalore. I've set the description_color property in the style dictionary to "white" with the aim of having white text, but it doesn't seem to work as expected.

Here's the relevant part of my code:

```
    import ipywidgets as widgets

    `    text_input = widgets.Text(
        value="",
        description="OCSF field:",
        style={"description_width": "initial", "description_color": "white"},
        layout=widgets.Layout(width='70%'),
    )

    text_input`
```

I tried this in Datalore (which is where I need it to work) but it doesn't work in jupyter notebook as well.

Is there supposed to be another method to set the color of the text?

Answer (score 0):

#### For Jupyter running current tech (JupyterLab 3.4+ or 4 or Jupyter Notebook 7+) and IPywidgets 8+

##### TL;DR

```py
import ipywidgets as widgets
display(widgets.HTML("""
<style>
.my-label-style label {
    color: purple !important;
    font-weight: bold !important;
}
</style>
"""))
text_input = widgets.Text(
        value="",
        description="OCSF field:",
        style={"description_width": "initial"},
        layout=widgets.Layout(width='70%'),  _dom_classes=["my-label-style"]
    )

text_input
```

#### THE DETAILS

You can run the following [based on the documentation](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Widget%20Styling.html#the-style-attribute) to get the list of the style attributes for a `text_input` widget you created with your code block:

```py
text_input.style.keys
```

At present that gives:

```
['_model_module',
 '_model_module_version',
 '_model_name',
 '_view_count',
 '_view_module',
 '_view_module_version',
 '_view_name',
 'background',
 'description_width',
 'font_size',
 'text_color']
```

If you try `text_color`, like so:

```py
import ipywidgets as widgets
text_input = widgets.Text(
        value="",
        description="OCSF field:",
        style={"description_width": "initial", "text_color": "red"},
        layout=widgets.Layout(width='70%'),
    )

text_input
```

You'll see that doesn't give you want you want.
**You'll see it colors the text you are entering and not the description.**.
So we've exhausted the present style attributes available. Not to worry though, read on...

#### Adjusting the description text styling

You can customize things by looking at what they are referenced as using developer tools and using CSS as spelled out [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/how-can-i-set-the-height-of-a-pywidgets-text/15395/3?u=fomightez). A number of other possibilities/variations exist and are touched on in that thread.

#### Specific example: Taking your code block and adapting it to make the description text purple and bold

Something like your specific example based on [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/widgets-styling-examples-is-this-conventional-or-a-hack/11833?u=fomightez) and **mostly [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/how-can-i-set-the-height-of-a-pywidgets-text/15395/3?u=fomightez)**:

```py
import ipywidgets as widgets
display(widgets.HTML("""
<style>
.my-label-style label {
    color: purple !important;
    font-weight: bold !important;
}
</style>
"""))
text_input = widgets.Text(
        value="",
        description="OCSF field:",
        style={"description_width": "initial"},
        layout=widgets.Layout(width='70%'),  _dom_classes=["my-label-style"]
    )

text_input
```

Result:
[image]

#### Alternative combining widgets?

You could probably remove the description and add in HTML next to the Text input area suing an HBox, something along the lines of what is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43028077/8508004); however, what I outlined above is definitely more directly addressing the OP's question.