# Ipywidgets appear separated when displaying them

Tags: python, widget, ipywidgets

I am creating two simple widgets with `ipywidget` and when displaying them, I need them to be close to each other. However the default is not showing them like this.

```
import ipywidgets as widgets

label = widgets.Label(value='test:')
checkbox = widgets.Checkbox(indent=False)
float_text = widgets.FloatText()

widgets_box = widgets.HBox([label, checkbox, float_text])
display(widgets_box)
```

Why is that? How to i put the Floattext widget just next to the checkbox?

[image]

Comment: This question / answers may be what you're looking.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37013489/how-to-align-and-place-ipywidgets

Comment: This link in particular: https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Widget%20Layout.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That happens because each widget has a predefined "factory size" that is set by its internal [layout property](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/7.6.3/examples/Widget%20Styling.html#The-layout-attribute). The internal layout of a widget defines how big that component should be on the screen.

This information is used `HBox` and the other types of Layout Managers to figure out how much screen space each widget on the list needs. So as you can imagine, the default size of a `Checkbox` is quite large.

One solution to this problem is to overwrite the predefined width of large widgets when they are created by setting a custom `layout` with a smaller size.
Here is an example:

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display

label = widgets.Label(value='test:', layout={'width': '30px'})
checkbox = widgets.Checkbox(indent=False, layout={'width': '20px'})
float_text = widgets.FloatText()

widgets_box = widgets.HBox([label, checkbox, float_text])
display(widgets_box)
```

A comparison between the original implementation and one that uses custom layouts:

[image]